# Alert that prevents any browser action until cleared

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate text and I use an alert() to let the user know when the text isn't valid. My only problem is that, at least with FF4 for me, the alert doesn't do anything to block them from doing things like the back and forward buttons, so if the text isn't valid they can still press back and it will not be validated.

Is there a way to make the alert so that nothing can be done to the browser until the alert is cleared away?

Comment: And if they disable their javascript, it won't matter at all.  Validation client side is a good thing, but should be complementary to server side validation.  My suggestion would be to not obsess with restricting user behaviors client side, just inform them of the problem.  And if they don't fix it before posting the data, send them back to the page with an informative message.

Comment: I would avoid using alert. Might be better in a PHP approach.

Comment: Alerts that block the browser are very bad from a user experience perspective. That's why FF4 has changed to non-blocking alerts. and I expect some other browsers to follow that philosophy soon.

Comment: What happens if your alert is caught in an endless loop or an event handler like `onmousemove`? Don't hold your users captive.

Comment: I just wanted a way to force the user to enter something into an input field. I obviously can prevent them from leaving it blank while going forward, but not while going backward, hence the question. Brad seems to have gotten it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind to [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) and make the user proceed the "correct" way until they get it right.

However, something tells me you need to fix your work-flow and not try to circumvent the user doing what they'd like (programmers always lose).

Answer (score 1):

No, and there shouldn't be. There used to be truly modal alerts, but they were abused like crazy. Same as with no-URL popups and so on. It's a good thing we're rid of them.

In any case, as a web user, I'd expect the back button to always be safe and not leave the application in an inconsistent state. That's probably a better approach

Answer (score 1):

I can't really think of anything that is so important to validate to prevent any other functionaluty and you can never truly achieve this on the client side and if you really have to then you should set a variable on the serverside, in the database for that user lets call it user_preventaction and lets say you set it to TRUE when the page loads that will not change until the input you want is validated and set back to FALSE. Then any page the user tries to access and preventaction is still TRUE it will render a page forcing them to validate whatever you think is so important that the user can even decide to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can replace the browser's alert box, the functionality is still built-in to the browser, so I don't think you can.

It would be better to consider alternative forms of error display.